# Replacing a character in a string costs?

Tags: c++

Is string class of stl mutable ? What does it cost to replace a character in a string with an integer cast to character ?

Answer (score 3):

1) Yes, it's mutable. Both operator[] and at() return non-const references to characters and can be used on the left hand side: `name[7] = 'X'`, or `name.at(7) = 'X'` if you want bounds-checking.

2) The cost to change a single character is very low: very close or the same as a C-string  (plus the cost of the bounds-checking with `at()`.) While not required by the standard, all implementations of std::string store the string in a contiguous block of memory (if I remember Meyers correctly), so changing a character in-place will be constant time.

See also the [boost string algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/string_algo.html), which generally provide both copy and in-place versions of popular string manipulations.

Comment: The spec does not require the internal representation to be contiguous, but it _does_ require both `at` and `operator[]` to be constant time.

Comment: With C++0x the contiguity becomes a requirement for `std::string` implementations.

Comment: awesome! Thanks Nemo and pmr!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can modify the contents of an [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/).

For example, using [`std::string::operator[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/) :

```
std::string str("foo");
str[0] = 'b';
std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

will output `"boo"`.

The cost of replacing a single character, is whatever copying a character to that memory location costs on your platform. Probably not much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's mutable.

If you mean something like:

```
std::string s("space\n");
int i = 'i';
s[2] = (char)i;
std::cout << s; // prints 'spice'
```

The details are implementation-defined, but the third line typically consists of:

1. Load a pointer value from the string
2. Add an index to it
3. Perform a byte store to that address

So it's cheap. There might be bounds checks and so on in debug mode, and there could be other code in there, but the above is basically what it has to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Linear to find a character (but constant if you know the index already). The actual replacement is constant time assuming the literal meaning if your question. The replacement would be linear in the number of characters after the replacement point if you actually mean a string representation of the integer.